# Updated collided sprite only

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have a very simple game that I'm playing around with, built off the touch/physics example. Basically what happens, is, when you touch the screen it creates a shape with a body and bounces around with box2d. Now, what I would like to do is when that specific sprite collides with anything at all, it will change the current frame to "1" for a moment then go back to the original.

I have it somewhat working, but whenever any sprite collides with anything it only updates the most recently created sprite. This is my collision detecting:

```
private ContactListener createContactListener()
    {
        ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
                face.animate(new long[] { 50, 10}, new int[] {1, 0}, 0);; 


            }

            @Override
            public void endContact(Contact contact) {

            }

            @Override
            public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

            }

            @Override
            public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

            }

        };
        return contactListener;
    }
```

As I said, I think I am close I just can't seem to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you've show enough information on here.  What is face?  and how is it stored?  You are likely having something static in the class that you don't expect.

Comment: Face is a sprite with a body attached to it. When the scene is created it creates the physics world and gravity follows the accelerometer. When you touch anywhere on the screen it creates "face" and its body and they bounce around. So, when you touch the scene 5 times you make 5 faces. I wanted each one, when colliding with anything, to switch to another frame for a brief moment, then go back to its original frame.

Answer (score 0):

With the contact listener it will not be called individually for two colliding bodies. What I mean is that when BodyA collides with BodyB only one contact listener callback is called. You only update the instance of the class to which the contact listener is registered to.

What you need to do is to pass the instance of the class to which the face belongs to as a userData when you register the listener (for each one). Then you can retrieve the instance from the Contact by :

```
FaceClass* fcA = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData();
FaceClass* fcB = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData();
```

Then call a function within the retrieved instances which will do what you need, maybe something like "updateOnCollision".

```
fcA.updateOnCollision();
fcB.updateOnCollision();
```

P.S. I wrote the code from head and my Jave is bad so might need a bit of adjustment.